Is it stealing to use a VPN?
A VPN is a software that hides your IP address, allowing you to appear online as if you are in a different place. Some companies have different options or prices for various locations.
Is it considered stealing to use a VPN to take advantage of a lower price?

Main use of VPN in industry is to connect two separated networks, in two separated locations, so they appears as a single network to his users. That make using the company resources (email servers, data base servers, etc) transparent and equally accessible no matter where are you working. It also simplify operations, because you don't need to touch users PC, only the routers connecting both locations.

Second use, for individuals, is for accessing services with geographic restrictions (typically, services only for users in US). If you are US citizen traveling the world, probably need one to access the services you already paid for, even if for the moment you are abroad.

If you work from home, you need a VPN to access your employer network.

I know what a VPN is, I just mentioned the part relevant to the question.

A VPN doesn't "hide" your IP. It's use to access resources that otherwise will be impossible to reach. There is no deception involved, not intended.

@CandidMoe yes and no. Suppose a website says, "this item costs $100 if you are currently in Freedonia, $120 if you are currently anywhere else. Click here to confirm you are currently in Freedonia to get the discount. If you are not, we would absolutely refuse to sell you this item for $100 and will press charges against you." It stands to reason that clicking "yes" would be prohibited if not in Freedonia. But what if the website just automatically says "your location was detected as non-Freedonia, price is $120" and you use a VPN through Freedonia?

The website now cheerfully says "your location appears to be Freedonia, price is $100." Should that be read as a form of deception? It's a good question.

Let's add another wrinkle here: suppose the difference between your actual location and your VPN-apparent location is not a matter of price, but whether the item is available at all. Rabbi Hershel Shachter shlit'a views intellectual property as ownership over "the rights to make money on something." If the manufacturer has stopped trying to make any money off of it ... that could weigh into the decision. (Unless it really looks like they are simply going to release this item in a different market a few months later.)

Every tool can be used for nefarious things. You have a chef knife for cooking that can also be used to stab people. That's not make the knife a "criminal tool", as it was never intended for that use and it's not the reason for you having one.

But, at the end, using a VPN to get a lower price is a form of deception.

@CandidMoe One could more readily argue that covert (and sometimes illegal) price discrimination by the vendor is a form of deception, and unless the pricing differences are stated expressly by the vendor there is likely no problem with the purchaser using a VPN to get the lowest price.

@Fred As much as I hate price discrimination and capitalism, sellers justify it by saying that price is the result of a negotiation between two free parties. No one is forced to participate and the "free market" gives you alternatives. Can we negate the seller's right to quote a price as he please?

@CandidMoe I'm not saying price discrimination is necessarily illegal or against halacha. But if the seller is covertly hiding implicit price discrimination that discriminates on the basis of some proxy variable that typically correlates with another variable, he is not explicitly quoting a price for you based on location. Therefore, one can make a reasonable argument that using a VPN is legitimate.
